# Change slider's next and previous button to be previews of upcoming or previous pictures

Tags: javascript, html, slider

Hey so i have a slider and i need to change the next and previous button backgrounds to show a preview of the next and previous slide. I don't know if it's possible without jQuery but since i'm working on an all javascript slider i'd very much appreciate a javascript solution

This is the HTML

```
<body onload="Load()"
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slides" id="slide1">
        <img src="img/1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slides" id="slide2">
        <img src="img/2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slides" id="slide3">
        <img src="img/3.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ctrl">
      <div class="prev">
        <input type="button" onClick="prev();">
      </div>
      <div class="next">
        <input type="button" onClick="next();">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the Javascript

```
  nrSlide=3;
  function Load(){
    nrShown = 0;
    vect = new Array(nrSlide + 1);
    vect[0] = document.getElementById("slide1");
    vect[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    for (var i = 1; i < nrSlide; i++)
    {
      vect[i] = document.getElementById("slide" + (i+1));
    }
  }
  function next(){
    nrShown++;
    if(nrShown == nrSlide) {
      nrShown=0;
    }
    Effect();
  }
  function prev(){
    nrShown--;
    if(nrShown == -1) {
      nrShown = nrSlide -1;
    }
    Effect();
  }
  // Effect
  function Effect(){
    for (var i=0; i < nrSlide; i++){
      vect[i].style.opacity = "0";
      vect[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    vect[nrShown].style.opacity = "1";
    vect[nrShown].style.visibility = "visible";
  }
```

PS: I do realize that this is doable in jQuery but i need a javascript solution. And if you are going to downvot at least leave a reason

Comment: A fiddle or code snippet would be nice :-)

Comment: The code is already posted @Mouser

Comment: Yes, but with a fiddle when can actually see what your code does and fiddle with it :-)

Comment: @Mouser Oh, absolutely, give me a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 nrSlide=3;
  function Load(){
 nrShown = 0;
 vect = new Array(nrSlide + 1);
 vect[0] = document.getElementById("slide1");
 vect[0].style.visibility = "visible";
 for (var i = 1; i < nrSlide; i++)
 {
   vect[i] = document.getElementById("slide" + (i+1));
 }
                ShowNextPrev(nrShown);
  }
  function next(){
 nrShown++;
 if(nrShown == nrSlide) {
   nrShown=0;
 }
 ShowNextPrev(nrShown);
 Effect();
  }
  function prev(){
  
 nrShown--;
 if(nrShown == -1) {
   nrShown = nrSlide -1;
 }

 ShowNextPrev(nrShown);
 Effect();
  }
  
  function ShowNextPrev(nrShown)
  {

 var nrShown2 = nrShown == nrSlide-1 ? -1 : nrShown;
 
 document.querySelector(".next").querySelector("input").style.backgroundImage = "url("+document.querySelector(".slider").querySelectorAll("img")[nrShown2+1].src+")";
 document.querySelector(".next").querySelector("input").style.backgroundSize = "contain";   
  
 var nrShown3 = nrShown == 0 ? nrSlide : nrShown;
 document.querySelector(".prev").querySelector("input").style.backgroundImage = "url("+document.querySelector(".slider").querySelectorAll("img")[nrShown3-1].src+")";
 document.querySelector(".prev").querySelector("input").style.backgroundSize = "contain";   
  }
  
  // Effect
  function Effect(){
 for (var i=0; i < nrSlide; i++){
   vect[i].style.opacity = "0";
   vect[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
 vect[nrShown].style.opacity = "1";
 vect[nrShown].style.visibility = "visible";
 
  }

  Load();
```

```css
.ctrl > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.slides > img {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="ctrl">
    <div class="prev">
      <input type="button" onClick="prev();">
    </div>
    <div class="next">
      <input type="button" onClick="next();">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slide1">
    <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Ze9FLpwZjdE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAA8/YOtXVkTZpNs/photo.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slide2">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/femfoyou/angry-birds/256/angry-bird-green-icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slide3">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/femfoyou/angry-birds/256/angry-bird-black-icon.png">
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

This approach should do it. In plain JavaScript using `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll`. You just need the code. The CSS and HTML are just altered to make it work for the example.

Comment: Thanks this actually works! The only problem is that the first 2 don't show up until i go to the next or previous slide so that the preview start working. If you have any suggestions let me know otherwise i'll try to fix it on my own! Thanks again

Comment: Sorry from removing the selection, but i found some problems with your solution

Comment: @kiraken And those are?

Comment: The preview now initiates on `load`